# openstack heat: Add port to instance based on condition

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

I want to add port to the instance only if the name is zee_1

template file:

```
resources:

  vm_port_routable:
    type: OS::Neutron::Port
    properties:
      network: { get_param: abc_routable_net }
      name:
        str_replace:
          template: $stack_$name_routable_port
          params:
            $stack: { get_param: stack }
            $name: { get_param: vm_name }
      security_groups: [{ get_param: security_group }]
      fixed_ips:
        - ip_address: { get_param: port_ip_routable }

  test_vm_port_routable:
    type: OS::Neutron::Port
    properties:

      network: { get_param: test_zee_routable_net }
      name:
        str_replace:
          template: $stack_$name_routable_port
          params:
            $stack: { get_param: stack }
            $name: { get_param: vm_name }
      security_groups: [{ get_param: security_group }]
      fixed_ips:
        - ip_address: { get_param: test_port_ip_routable }

      zee_server:
        type: OS::Nova::Server
        properties:
          block_device_mapping_v2:
            - boot_index: 0
              delete_on_termination: false
              volume_id: { get_resource: root_volume }
              device_name: vda
              device_type: disk
            - boot_index: -1
              delete_on_termination: false
              volume_id: { get_param: backup_volume }
              device_name: vdc
              device_type: disk
          flavor: { get_param: flavor }
          key_name: { get_param: ssh_keypair }
          name: { get_param: vm_name }

          networks:
            - port: { get_resource: vm_port_routable }
            - port: { get_resource: test_vm_port_routable }
```

I want to add port "test_vm_port_routable" only if name is zee_1....

I tried with below condition but it is giving error :ERROR: The template section is invalid: conditions

```
conditions:
       create_prod_res: { equal: [{get_param: "vm_name"},"zee_1"]}
resources:

  vm_port_routable:
    type: OS::Neutron::Port
    properties:
      network: { get_param: abc_routable_net }
      name:
        str_replace:
          template: $stack_$name_routable_port
          params:
            $stack: { get_param: stack }
            $name: { get_param: vm_name }
      security_groups: [{ get_param: security_group }]
      fixed_ips:
        - ip_address: { get_param: port_ip_routable }

  test_vm_port_routable:
    type: OS::Neutron::Port
    properties:

      network: { get_param: test_zee_routable_net }
      name:
        str_replace:
          template: $stack_$name_routable_port
          params:
            $stack: { get_param: stack }
            $name: { get_param: vm_name }
      security_groups: [{ get_param: security_group }]
      fixed_ips:
        - ip_address: { get_param: test_port_ip_routable }

      zee_server:
        type: OS::Nova::Server
        properties:
          block_device_mapping_v2:
            - boot_index: 0
              delete_on_termination: false
              volume_id: { get_resource: root_volume }
              device_name: vda
              device_type: disk
            - boot_index: -1
              delete_on_termination: false
              volume_id: { get_param: backup_volume }
              device_name: vdc
              device_type: disk
          flavor: { get_param: flavor }
          key_name: { get_param: ssh_keypair }
          name: { get_param: vm_name }
          condition:create_prod_res  
          networks:
            - port: { get_resource: vm_port_routable }
            - port: { get_resource: test_vm_port_routable }
```

with the above changes to template it is failing
can some one help me in this .....

Comment: I don't see a `heat_template_version` in your template file, which means that depending on what Heat selects as a default you may not be able to use the `conditions` key.  What if you set `heat_template_version: pike` (or whichever version of openstack you're working with)?

Comment: I am using heat_template_version: 2014-10-16 .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [specification](https://docs.openstack.org/heat/pike/template_guide/hot_spec.html), you will note that support for the `conditions` section was only added in Newton.  So you need either:

```
heat_template_version: newton
```

Or:

```
heat_template_version: 2016-10-14
```

Or the equivalent for a later release.  If you're running an openstack release earlier than Newton, you simply won't be able to use this feature.

Comment: can you give some idea on how to do it in older version with out using if condition

Comment: here I have two instance and I have to add port to only one instance based on name.....